# SHA of SHA as signatures of composite objects

Tags: hash, signature, sha

I have a bunch of large objects, and structures of those, and vectors of those. It's important to check integrity of the composite objects sometimes; for that I'm using Sha256 "signature" of the objects.

There are at least two ways to define a signature of a composite object: by computing `sha` of concatenation of components, or by computing `sha` of the concatenations of `sha`s of the components.

That is, the 1st method signature of a vector `Object0, Object1, Object2` would be `sha(Object0 Object1 Object2)`, and the 2nd method would be `sha(sha(Object0) sha(Object1) sha(Object2))`.

It's a lot faster in what I'm doing to sign composite objects with the 2nd method. The question is, does this method, computing `sha`s of `sha`s, increase the chances of collisions? Do I sacrifice any security because I'm hashing not the objects but hashes of the objects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have described there is well known structure of [Merkle tree or hash tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merkle_tree). Git repository is basically giant Merkle tree.

Security of such structure is as strong as preimage resistance of hash function of your choice.

Answer (score -1):

Although I can't provide a mathematical proof for this, I'd say: No, it doesn't matter.